# how i can show my password on imageview touch?

Tags: android

i want to show my password when imageview is pressed and when i release  my touch at that time it should hide. For example if i press imageview for 2 minutes then password should be visible for 2 minute and when i release it should hide.

i have following code for check box

```
EditText mEtPwd;
CheckBox mCbShowPwd;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // get the password EditText
    mEtPwd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);
    // get the show/hide password Checkbox
    mCbShowPwd = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);

    // add onCheckedListener on checkbox
    // when user clicks on this checkbox, this is the handler.
    mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
            if (!isChecked) {
                    // show password
                mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            } else {
                    // hide password
                mEtPwd.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: You may be achieve this using the Gesture Detector i suggest to use the following url to achieve this ; http://codetheory.in/android-ontouchevent-ontouchlistener-motionevent-to-detect-common-gestures/

Comment: The given code and asked answer is not at all relevant. you want to show the password on ImageView but you written the code for checkbox. please write the question elaborately.

Comment: @RajanBhavsar... oky i check

Comment: @HariRam...dude i know that i say that this code is for check box n i want to do that on my image is touch

Comment: Hi Jaydeep in ACTION_DOWN and ACTION_UP You are able to Show and hide the Password as per your requirement. If there any query please suggest me.

Comment: @RajanBhavsar.... yes i i got my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In place of `CheckBox` use `ImageView` only and `setTouchListener()` for it, 
set `mPassField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_VISIBLE_PASSWORD);` for `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN` to show the password.

 and `mPassField.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);` in `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` to hide it back.

For example,

```
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                int action = event.getActionMasked();

                switch (action) {

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        // TODO show password
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE:
                        // TODO mask password
                        break;
                }

                return v.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @hoonj for giving example, this adds up alot readability and understandability. UP votes anyone ?? ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the input type of your EditText.

Make it a password field (hide password):

```
mEtPwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT | InputType.TYPE_TEXT_VARIATION_PASSWORD);
mEtPwd.setSelection(mEtPwd.getText().length());
```

Make it a normal field (show password):

```
mEtPwd.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
mEtPwd.setSelection(mEtPwd.getText().length());
```

Comment: u not get what i m want to ask

Answer (score 1):

Below are the code which is used to convert your editeText content into bitmap and place it into imageview while pressing long.

```
enter code here
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
static Bitmap bmp;
static EditText et;
static ImageView iv;
static Canvas ivCanvas; // We'll be using our own Canvas.

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    // Move this up to onCreate
    Bitmap ab = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            (R.drawable.ger));
    bmp = convertToMutable(ab); // Initialize it here with the contents of
                                // ab. This effectively clones it and makes
                                // it mutable.
    ab = null; // Dispose of ab.

    ivCanvas = new Canvas(bmp); // Create our Canvas!


et.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        //ADD HERE ABOUT CUT COPY PASTE  
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       updateCanvas();
    }
});

public void updateCanvas() {
    ivCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);

    ivCanvas.drawBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, null);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    ivCanvas.drawText(et.getText().toString(), 10, 10, paint);

    // Everything has been drawn to bmp, so we can set that here, now.
    iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

    // Removed the "catch" blocks so you can actually know when you're
    // getting errors! Feel free to re-add later.
}
```